# Use chunks from strsplit in Matlab for text file

Tags: matlab, organization

I have a list of files that I would like to merge. I also would like to extract the information from the file name and put it into the text file along with the information that I am merging.

Example:

name of file:

```
p01.male.cond.1.loud.txt
```

info in file:

```
0.015         120     50
0.12          121     52
0.23          119     53
0.4           122     59
```

I would like the file to look like this:

```
p01   male   cond  1  loud  0.015   120     50
p01   male   cond  1  loud  0.12    121     52
p01   male   cond  1  loud  0.23    119     53
p01   male   cond  1  loud  0.4     122     59
```

I used `strsplit` to extract the names from the file name but I do not know how to use the chunks from `strsplit` to put into a data file

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it, creating a new cell array and putting al the infos in it:

```
clear
clc
close all

FileName = 'p01.male.cond.1.loud.txt';

%// Set up the info from the file, in a cell array

InfoFile = {0.015         120     50;
0.12          121     52;
0.23          119     53;
0.4           122     59};

%//Get elements to put into file
NameElements = strsplit(FileName,'.')
```

Here `NameElements` looks like this:

```
NameElements = 

    'p01'    'male'    'cond'    '1'    'loud'    'txt'
```

Get the actual number of elements you wish to keep. Here they are the first 5  outputs of `strsplit`:

```
NumGoodElements = numel(NameElements)-1;
```

Initialize new cell array to place all elements and put `InfoFile` in it:

```
NewFile = cell(size(InfoFile,1),size(InfoFile,2)+NumGoodElements);

%// Put the info (numbers) in the cell array.
NewFile(:,NumGoodElements+1:end) = InfoFile;
```

At this point `NewFile` looks like this:

```
NewFile = 

    []    []    []    []    []    [0.0150]    [120]    [50]
    []    []    []    []    []    [0.1200]    [121]    [52]
    []    []    []    []    []    [0.2300]    [119]    [53]
    []    []    []    []    []    [0.4000]    [122]    [59]
```

And you only need to add the first 5 elements of `NameElements` into the cell array, repeating them 4 times to fill the whole array:

```
NewFile(:,1:NumGoodElements) = repmat(NameElements(1:NumGoodElements),size(InfoFile,1),1)
```

And the final output:

```
NewFile = 

    'p01'    'male'    'cond'    '1'    'loud'    [0.0150]    [120]    [50]
    'p01'    'male'    'cond'    '1'    'loud'    [0.1200]    [121]    [52]
    'p01'    'male'    'cond'    '1'    'loud'    [0.2300]    [119]    [53]
    'p01'    'male'    'cond'    '1'    'loud'    [0.4000]    [122]    [59]
```

In order to export that cell array to a text file, do the following using `fprintf`: (check [here](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/1107-export-cell-array-to-text-file) for the example by the Mathworks)

1) Open the file you wish to write into

```
fileID = fopen('FinalData.dat','w');
```

2) Define the format to assign to each column of the cell array

```
formatSpec = '%s %s %s %i %s %1.4f %3.0f %2.0f \n';
```

3) Loop through each row and write the content of the cell array in the file. Then close it.

```
[nrows,ncols] = size(NewFile);
for row = 1:nrows
    fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,C{row,:});
end

fclose(fileID);
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there a way to do this more generally? I have about 600 files that all have different names and different content.

Comment: Mhh could you put the above code in a for loop? That should be straight forward to generalize; I think :)

Comment: I put it in a for loop but now I am getting this error: `Error in ==> runanalysis at 35
    chunks=strsplit(filename, '.'); %split
    the filename into component chunks,
    where the chunks are delimited by a
    period: '.'`